# The encoding mode changes？ after setting quote option when spark dataframe writes CSV

Tags: apache-spark

```
myDf.repartition(1).write
      .format("csv")
      .save("Path to save file")
```

i got a  datafram like this in csv:
[CSV1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH5iZ.png)

and its encoding is UTF-8

but when i add option :

```
myDf.repartition(1).write
      .format("csv")
      .option("quote","")
      .save("Path to save file")
```

it turns out that the csv file encoding changed to ansi
[csv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zYhx.png)

i am very confused , how can i delete the quote " ?

Comment: What are u trying to do ? What is the final output that u require?

Comment: My current solution is to write text and change the suffix

Answer (score 0):

Its `NUL` because you added nothing as quote. What do you want to do? You can delete the quote with just deleting the option.